# How to make a group conditional?

Tags: regex

I would like to:

- analyze a string looking for the sequence `/something here/` which may or may not be present
- know when this sequence is the only thing in the string (= the whole string is just this sequence).

By using the regex `(.*)(\/(.+)\/)(.*)` and the following test strings I almost got what I wanted (the regex and tests trings are available at https://regex101.com/r/y9SEEp/1):

```
hello world /a title/ some words  -> match (group 3) + something else (group 1 and group 4)
hello world /a title/             -> match (group 3) + something else (group 1)
/a title/ some words              -> match (group 3) + something else (group 4)
/a title/                         -> match (group 3)
hello world some words            -> only something else -- BUT THIS ONE DOES NOT WORK
```

The last test string fails the regex - I think it would be enough to be able to make `(\/(.+)\/)` conditional but I do not know how to write that.

Or should I go for another strategy?

Comment: may be something like [`^([^\/\r\n]*)(?:\/([^\/]+)\/)?(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/l0gK2T/1)

Comment: @JvdV: I do not care, in that case I just want to know that there was no `/something/` match (I will check whether the string is not empty earlier in my code)

Comment: You could also exclude matching the `/` in all 3 parts and use 3 capture groups `^([^/\r\n]*)(?:(/[^/\r\n]+/)(?:([^/\r\n]+))?)?` https://regex101.com/r/aWWbY1/1 To prevent matching an empty string you might use a lookahead https://regex101.com/r/yhqxkc/1

Comment: @JvdV: I am not sure I understand. I am not interested in anything beyond `/what is between these separators/` + know if they are present + know if they are the whole string. In practival terms, I will have a sentence from which I will extract `/what is between these separators/` and process what remains afterwards. What remains can be an empty string.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you are saying. Would something along the lines of `^[^\/\n]*(?:\/(.*?)\/)?.*$` work, grabbing anything from 1st capture group?

Comment: @JvdV: ah, this is a cool one (I put it here: https://regex101.com/r/y9SEEp/2). Why is there a `\n`?

Comment: @WoJ that was for demonstration purposes since `[^\/]` would match a newline character. But if you parse these single lines it shouldn't be a problem leaving it out. Note that I changed it to include a non-capturing group holding the 1st capture group [here](https://regex101.com/r/j2VYKX/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
(.*)(\/(.+)\/|^.*)(.*)
```

Here, if the third group is not matched, then you force to "restart" from the beginning of the string (using `^`) and match the whole string with group 2.

```
hello world /a title/ some words  -> match (group 3) + something else (group 1 and group 4)
hello world /a title/             -> match (group 3) + something else (group 1)
/a title/ some words              -> match (group 3) + something else (group 4)
/a title/                         -> match (group 3)
hello world some words            -> only something else (group 2)
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/T4RnpZ/1